# CSS parent aware of stacked children

Tags: html, css, css-position, stacked

I have two images stacked on top of eachother. My solution works and I use position absolute.

The downside of this approach is that the parent element is not aware of the children boundaries and does therefor not adapt the container to it.

**How can I make the parent automatically adapt its size to these children?**

- Flex and Grid solutions are accepted as well as position absolute solutions.
- I don't want to use javascript.
- I don't want to hack in a solution where I need to manually set a height to the container.
- It's fine if it works with modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Edge)

*I think I've read about a solution a long time ago involving grid, but I'm not sure.*

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee; /* DOES NOT FILL UP */
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

img:last-child {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/140">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/139">
</div>

Something below
```

Comment: Do you need this for images that are (almost) the exact same size, as in the given example - or for just _completely_ arbitrary combinations of image dimensions?

Comment: (And do you need only two images stuck on top of each other like that, or maybe half a dozen, or - “unlimited”?)

Comment: @CBroe My idea is that it could be a universal solution. Do you have different solutions for different cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS grid like below. The trick is to make both images on the same row/column:

```css
.box {
  display:grid;
  background: lightblue; 
  /* remove the below if you want full width */
  width:-moz-fit-content; 
  width:fit-content;
}

img {
  grid-row:1;
  grid-column:1;
}

img:last-child {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/140">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/139">
</div>

Something below
```

Also like below using `position:absolute` with better support:

```css
.box {
  display: table; /* remove this if you want full width */
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

img:last-child {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/140">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/139">
</div>

Something below
```

A third solution with negative margin:

```css
.box {
  display: table; /* remove this if you want full width */
  background: lightblue;
}

img {
 vertical-align:top;
}

img:last-child {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left:-9rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/140">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/139">
</div>

Something below
```

Comment: Nice! It seems to work just as expected at a first glance. I don't know why you got a downvote. I gave it an upvote this far. Now I have a grid solution and a flex solution, so I need to pick one as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JensTörnell you can still wait, I am sure more solution will come ;)

Comment: `width: max-content;` instead of `width:fit-content;` for Firefox

Comment: @JensTörnell added another idea more supported

Comment: @JensTörnell added a third solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif In the end I use your grid solution. I guess it would have worked with flex and table as well. I find the table version a bit hackish because of it not being much like a table. Also if I don't need z-index, I prefer solutions without it. I did not need to use width: fit-content in my code because when using a flex wrapper, flex takes over that behaviour.

Comment: @JensTörnell display:table is equivalent to width:fit-content. It's not needed for the trick. It's used to reduce the width and it's simply more supported than fit-content. Since you are using flex wrapper you can deleted if like you did for width:fit-content

Answer (score 3):

you can do this just using margins in a flex container, just adjust margins as per your need

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  background: #eee; /* DOES NOT FILL UP */
display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}


img:last-child {
      margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-left: -7rem
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/140">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/139">
</div>

Something below
```

Comment: Nice solution! It works just as expected. I like that there are both flex and grid solutions to pick from.